# Python subprocess.run ignores --exclude clause

Tags: python, bash, subprocess

I have one issue with `subprocess.run`.

This command in a Bash shell works without any problem:

```bash
tar -C '/home/' --exclude={'/home/user1/.cache','/home/user1/.config'} -caf '/transito/user1.tar' '/home/user1' > /dev/null 2>&1
```

But if I execute it through Python:

```bash
cmd = "tar -C '/home/' --exclude={'/home/user1/.cache','/home/user1/.config'} -caf '/transito/user1.tar' '/home/user1' > /dev/null 2>&1"
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

The execution works without errors but the --exclude clause is not considered.

Why?

Comment: works for me, would you format properly your code and expand as to why you think it's not considering the exclude clause?

Comment: @sj95126 actually bash curly expansion does not happen at python level, that won't work at all actually

Comment: @sj95126 because it doesn't. I'm adding an answer to point out that

Answer (score 2):

Whether or not curly brace expansion is handled correctly depends on what the standard system shell is. By default, `subprocess.run()` invokes `/bin/sh`. On systems like Linux, `/bin/sh` is `bash`. On others, such as FreeBSD, it's a different shell that doesn't support brace expansion.

To ensure the subprocess runs with a shell that can handle braces properly, you can tell `subprocess.run()` what shell to use with the `executable` argument:

```
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, executable='/bin/bash')
```

As a simple example of this, here's a system where `/bin/sh` is `bash`:

```
>>> subprocess.run("echo foo={a,b}", shell=True)
foo=a foo=b
```

and one where it's not:

```
>>> subprocess.run("echo foo={a,b}", shell=True)
foo={a,b}
```

but specifying another shell works:

```
>>> subprocess.run("echo foo={a,b}", shell=True, executable='/usr/pkg/bin/bash')
foo=a foo=b
```

Comment: Great, I solved it:  result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/bash").

Answer (score 1):

Bash curly expansion doesn't work inside Python and will be sent by subprocess as they are - they will not be expanded, regardless of the arguments you use on run().

*Edit: unless of course the argument `executable='/bin/bash'` as stated on [the other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74750357/7839535) which seems to work after all*

In a bash shell,

```bash
--exclude {'/home/user1/.cache','/home/user1/.config'}
```

becomes:

```bash
--exclude=/home/user1/.cache --exclude=/home/user1/.config
```

So to achieve the same result, in Python it must be expressed like this (one of the possible ways) before sending the command string to subprocess.run:

```py
' '.join(["--exclude=" + path for path in ['/home/user1/.cache','/home/user1/.config']])
```

```py
cmd = "tar -C '/home/' " + ' '.join(["--exclude=" + path for path in ['/home/user1/.cache','/home/user1/.config']]) + " -caf '/transito/user1.tar' '/home/user1' > /dev/null 2>&1"
print(cmd) # output: "tar -C '/home/' --exclude=/home/user1/.cache --exclude=/home/user1/.config -caf '/transito/user1.tar' '/home/user1' > /dev/null 2>&1"
subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
```

Comment: Super, thank you for the explanation, now I know why this appened, the problem was the "shell" used. Thank you to your explanation and the  response of sj95126 I solved easily with:  result = subprocess.run(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, executable="/bin/bash")